# Using Euler's assumption .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Using Euler's Assumption determine:
$$ 2^{64}\mod 99 $$
Help me. 
$$a^{\phi (m) } \equiv 1 \mod m $$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We have $\varphi(99)=60$, and $2^{64}=2^{60}2^4$.

**Remark:** The result we are using is usually called Euler's *Theorem*.